# CSS - Flex Sidebar - full height of the page - Weebly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, weebly

I have been working on a Weebly website: https://testerbuyer.weebly.com/

The issue is the sidebar menu on the left.

If the sidebar menu has only a few menu items, the sidebar covers full height of the page and sticks to the page. If the menu has many items like mine does, the sidebar starts moving with the page with is totally fine, but al least I need to stretch it to full height of the content.

So I'm trying to get the sidebar to cover the full height of the page's content.

The sidebar is set in flex, so I've been trying to use all kinds of tutorials I could find on setting the sidebar full heigh, there are a few, but I just can't seem to be able to make it working.

Currently the sidebars `min-height` property is set to be `100vh`.

I've been trying `min-height: 100%, flex: 1;` nothing seems to strech it full height.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited some of your CSS code below here, first I am rewriting position absolute to fixed and min-height to the height and then add overflow scroll property, I hope your problem solved.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 64.0625em){
    body.nav-position-sidebar .header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 260px;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 40px;
        border-bottom: none;
        /* display: flex; */
        /* flex-direction: row; */
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do like your solution, but what if I wanted the sidebar to be basically the entire length of the content length and then scroll up and down together with the content?
Instead of the scrollbar.

Comment: if you needed the relative scroll then you just talk the site position: absolute, height: 100vh; and min-height: 100%

Comment: Awesome that works great too. Thanks so much for your help, you're a legend!

Comment: Wellcome @Joe Bloggs